# Bootstrap Modal show current data on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**My original issue:**

I know that when this gets coded, the variables get written when the request is sent from the server. So I'll probably have to use JQuery, but I'm lost on where to even start (I don't know JS).

This code works when I refresh the page, but I want it to refresh the data being displayed when the modal is clicked on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**My self found fix, for others to view:**

Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal fade ajaxmodal" id="logModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="logModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Trace Logging</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
```

JS:

```
$('.ajaxmodal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#modal-body').load('trace.php');
});
```

trace.php has formatted html that displays on click perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my original question to contain my answer as well.